# Breezejs, Unable to locate property xxxxx

Tags: model, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I keep getting an error while using my $select=Gallery/Categories query(projection) for some reason.. the error Im getting is this:

> "Unable to locate property 'Categories' on type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Web.Core.Models.GalleryModel]'."

This is my current model:

```
public class GalleryModel : BaseModel
{
    public ICollection<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Where the BaseModel simply has a few additional properties.. such as

```
public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
```

Any ideas why it might be throwing this error?
The wierd thing is that if I dont add my projection, then it seems to find the property and respond with the full-blown json.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: As of v 1.3.1 Breeze now DOES support inheritance.

Breeze does not yet support inheritance, but it is on our roadmap.  Please vote for this feature on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model) to indicate that you feel that it is important. We take this venue very seriously in prioritizing which features we add next.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with version 1.3.6!   
    ```public class User : IUser<int>, IAuditable
    {
     public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }```

Comment: GET `/usuarios?$orderby=Name&$select=Name,Id` the error: `Unable to locate property 'Name' on type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandWrapper`1[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.User]'.`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem can be produced for some reasons. In my experience using breeze with web API and entity framework, I have discovered that you have to define your classes in a very especific way to do all work fine. And I think that the main reason of your problem can be that:

```
public class GalleryModel : BaseModel
{
    public **virtual** ICollection<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

You should use virtual in the definition of the relations.

Also I reccomed you to do that:

```
public class CategoryModel : BaseModel
{
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public virtual CategoryModel Category{ get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the intherance is not a problem, I have implemented something very similar and it worked for me. The intherance that is not supported in breeze is when you want to convert a table in different objects according to a discriminator.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, "breeze can't find property xyz of entityType xxx".
I found two solutions, either:

1.) In your datacontext (or entityManagerFactory.. whatever), remove the line

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```

or better,

2.) Ensure that all of your js uses camelCase convention.